# Problem with multivaluedness of $(-1)^{\frac 14}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, prime-numbers, multivalued-functions

Assume that $p\equiv3\mod4$ is an odd prime and $k$ an odd number. Then $$m=(-1)^{\frac{p^k-p^{k-1}+2}{4}}$$ seems to be always the value $1$ (?). This would be interesting how one can prove this - I made some congruence reasoning but in that way I cant find a solution for the problem.

Now the core of my question : if I set $(-1)^{\frac 14}=e^{\frac{-\pi i}{4}}$
then I reach by calculation with complex numbers in exponential form a formula I would like to have $$m=(-i)(-1)^{\frac{p^k-p^{k-1}}{4}}$$

But when I do the same calculation setting $(-1)^{\frac 14}=e^{\frac{+\pi i}{4}}$ I get $$m=i(-1)^{\frac{p^k-p^{k-1}}{4}}$$ which is not the one which I am looking for.

I calculated e.g. thus $$e^{\frac{-\pi i}{4}(p^k-p^{k-1}+2)}=e^{\frac{-\pi i}{4}(p^k-p^{k-1})}e^{-\frac{\pi i}{2}}=(-i)(-1)^{\frac{p^k-p^{k-1}}{4}}$$

Comment: $p\equiv \{3,-1\} \pmod{\!8}$. Two cases: 1) $p\equiv 3\pmod{\!8}\,\Rightarrow\, p^k-p^{k-1}+2\equiv 3^k-3^{k-1}+2\equiv 3-1+2\equiv 4\pmod{8}$, so $m=-1$. 2) $p\equiv -1\pmod{\!8}\,\Rightarrow\, p^k-p^{k-1}+2\equiv (-1)^k-(-1)^{k-1}+2\equiv -1-1+2\equiv 0\pmod{\!8}$, so $m=1$. Conclusion: $m=1$ if $p\equiv 3\pmod{\!8}$; $m=-1$ if $p\equiv 7\pmod{\!8}$.

Comment: I meant $m=1$ if $p\equiv 7\pmod{\!8}$; $m=-1$ if $p\equiv 3\pmod{\!3}$, of course. sorry.

Comment: @Wolfgang Tintemann just in case (-1) is also the value of the Möbius function for a prime number, $\mu (p) = -1$ so maybe you could find other relationships through that point.

Comment: You are using different values for $(-1)^\frac{1}{4}$ and getting different answers. What is the question?

Comment: @Prometheus Its because I get $$m=z(-1)^{\frac{p^k-p^{k-1}}{4}}$$ with either $z=-i$ or $z=i$ depending on the way I calculate. But it should be $z=-i$ the only correct value. I dont know according to what rule e.g. CAS programs choose the value of $(-1)^{\frac 14}$.

Comment: Still not clear what the question is. Do you want to prove that formula, or do you want to know if there's a mistake in your calculation? Or do you want to know how the program computes it?

Comment: I am looking for a proof of the correct value of the $z$-value above. It should be $-i$ ( or other results have to be checked ). But my way of proving gives me two values of $z$ depending on the value of $(-1)^{\frac 14}$ I choose. Also would be interesting why e.g Maple chooses $i$ when four values are possible ("Hauptwert" in German ?).